# C++ Safe returning a pointer to an iterater after map insert?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

So I have some C++ classes that use a map and key class for a sort of data structure. In my insert method I use the typical map.insert. I want this function to return a pointer so I can modify some values (not the one used for comparison) inside the element inserted. So I was wondering if this is safe to this..

```
template<typename T>
NodeT<T> *  TreeT<T>::
MakeNode(PointT point)
{
  NodeT<T> * prNode = new NodeT<T>;

    //set the contents for the node
  prNode->SetNode(point, m_dTolerance);


  //Create the key class using the 
  VectorKey key(point, m_dTolerance);

  //Store the key,node as a pair for easy access 
  return_val = m_tree.insert( pair<VectorKey, NodeT<T> >(key, *prNode) );
  if (return_val.second == false)
    //if return_val.second is false it wasnt inserted
    prNode = NULL;
  else
   //it was inserted, get a pointer to node
    prNode = &(return_val.first->second); //is this safe if I plan to use it later?

  return prNode;
```

}

I seemed to learn the hard way that my original pointer (the one I created with new), was pointing to the wrong element after the insert. Can anyone tell me why that is? So I used the return_val iterator to get the right pointer. I kinda dont want to return an iterator but if its safer then I do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to have troubles in your code with pointers and values. First you allocate an object on a heap ( with new Node )
Then you use a copy of that object to sore within your map.
PS. And then you loose original object forever as do not free memory which leads to memory leak.

In your case - it is invalid because you return pointer to object which can be deleted at any time ( for example next time you add something to your map and map decides to reallocate it's tree, so it will copy objects to different places ).
Storing pointers as map values prevents this. The only thing you need to remember to clear them up when removing object from map and when removing map itself.
The easy way to handle that would be using smart pointers (boost::shared_ptr for example ) or smart map class (boost::ptr_map for example ).

To fix that - use pointers everywhere ( store a pointer as a map value ).
This way - you will be able to return pointer from this function and it will be valid.
So just turn your map to map*> and this should fix most of your problems.
Do not forger to delete objects when erasing them from the map.

Comment: so when I dereferenced the new node it stored the copy?

Comment: >so when I dereferenced the new node it stored the copy?
 Yes ( sorry for taking so long to respond =) )

Answer (score 1):

This code sample is interesting because contains a several things wrongs or to avoid.

**Implementation**

The most important things are been said (mainly by Bogolt):

- You are leaking memory, because allocate `NodeT<T>` from the heap and never free it again, since `map` will allocate a copy of the object, not the pointer. Indeed, you specify as parameter `*prNode`, not `prNode`.
- You use the heap to allocate the object (will be copied into the `map`), but you assume you always allocate the object. Despite it will be the very most probably case, that is not alway true: `new` operator would be return null or throw a `bad_alloc` exception. The code does not handle it.
- Anyway, you use the heap when is not really needed. (And you see the problems are you intriducing because that). You can just create the object in the stack and then insert into the map, avoiding the previous problems and typing less code.

**Design**

- The function returns a pointer to the element in the map. Depending the program, is possible this is safe. But what happens if the code reference the pointer when the object is removed from the map? Better, if you are returning pointer, do not return a raw pointer. Use smart pointer (`shared_ptr` in this case) instead. Using `shared_ptr` you will have not problems with the object life.
- Other reason to use smart pointers: because the insertion into the map imply a copy of the element, you are imposing a requirement to `NodeT<T>`: it has to be copy constructible. May be this requirement is not important for performance, but may be in other circumstances copying the object have drawbacks. If you use smart pointer (or `boost::ptr_map`), the object will be created just once and is not copied.

**Style**

Just some suggestion, but not too important:

- instead type `pair<VectorKey, NodeT<T> >(key, *prNode)`, type `make_pair(key, *prNode)`. The code is more compact and clearer typing less.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd say that depends on is your map alive longer than anything that could use (and store) the pointer.

If yes, (ie, it's in some sort of singleton), you could go with it, but not very safe anyway since any code could delete the pointer.

The best option is to store boost::shared_ptr (or std:: since c++11) instead of raw pointers in your mapn and return only a weak_ptr after insertion.

That way, you're sure no other code can delete your pointer as long as the map holds it, and that no one can use a pointer that has been erased from the map.